# change image in dynamic list view

Tags: java, android

How can i change image in list view at rum time.
I want to change `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"` according to the gender .

here xml

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="20px"
            android:textColor="#dc6800"/>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
            android:background="@drawable/people" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:paddingBottom="1px" 
            android:visibility="invisible">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="20px"
            android:textColor="#dc6800"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

java code :

```
    for (Element group : allGroups) {
        String empID = XMLUtil.getNodeValue(group, EMPID );
        String empName = XMLUtil.getNodeValue(group, NAME );
        String gender = XMLUtil.getNodeValue(group, GENDER );
        gropusMap.put(empID , group);

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(NAME , empName);
        map.put(EMPID , empID);
        if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("female")){
            map.put(PHOTO , "female");
        }else {
            map.put(PHOTO , "male");
        }

        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems , R.layout.list_item, new String[] { NAME, EMPID,PHOTO }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.empid ,R.id.imageView });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {.
```

.
..
.
.

Comment: I would suggest you to create your list item in your java code itself

Comment: Do you want to change the content of the ImageView or the TextView, or do you want to change where it is displayed (`toLeftOf` / `toRightOf`)?

Comment: I want to change the imageview. i wanna change the image depends on the gender. if gender is male the show male image else female image.